# Line break adjustment of div tag and input tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problem working with DIV Tag and Form input fields. I get the value of input field using javascript. Javascript working fine. It gets the input field value and displays in a DIV tag. The problem is, when i give a long input or long sentence, it displays in the div tag as it is. I want it to be displayed not in a long single line but in the form of paragraph. Here is my code.

```
<script>
function myFunc(){
    var str = document.myform.aaa.value;
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=str;
}
</script>



<form>
<input type="text" name="aaa" />
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="myFunc();" >
</form>

<div id="mydiv" width="500px" height="300px">Old text</div>
```

If i give it an input for example:

```
hello there, how are you hello there, how are youhello there, how are youhello there.
```

it displays it in a single line instead of paragraph format. I want it to display the above sentence in this form:

```
hello there, how are you hello there, 
how are youhello there, how are youhello 
there.
```

I have somewhat sort it out myself. I mean to say, if i write a sentence with spaces, it works fine but if there is a long line of letters without any space, then it does not work. What i want is, either i can type with space and without space, it should work both ways.

Comment: So give the div a set width.

Comment: @j08691... i set its width 500px and height 300px. Still not working

Comment: Maybe your width is too wide. Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yAwrH/1/

Comment: @j08691... i have checked your link. It working there. But i have tried my code in Firefox 18, Opera, Safari but no use.

Comment: Do you have other CSS or JavaScript that might be affecting the content?

Comment: I copied the code from you given link, that works fine. But, the problem is, when i grab the input field value and display it using the same div, it creates the same problem again. Even i tried yours code.

Comment: No. I do not have any other CSS and Javascript. Just to make it work, i am implementing it totally separate.

Comment: Your code works with hard code only. But if i try to display my input using using input field, it does not work. Even i tried your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css to set the `width` and `height` of the `<div>` rather than attributes.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFsnx/1)

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">Old text</div>
```

Better yet create a style:

```
.comments {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

<div id="mydiv" class="comments">Old text</div>
```

Use the word-wrap to fix the issue where there is no spaces.

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Comment: @Gabe... its not working bro. It seems easy but nothing is working.

Comment: You are right. But i would suggest you to write a small code and try it in any browser instead of using Fiddle. Input field value should be grabbed and the container div should not be overflown. You will see for yourself, it will not work

Comment: @Gabe.. thanks for you help. You know what? it works if there is space in a sentence. But it does not work if there is not space in a sentence. For example: it works with "Hello, how are you how are you". But it does not work with "HellohowareyouHellohowareyouHellohowareyouHellohowareyouHellohowareyouHellohowareyou"

Comment: You would have to use `word-wrap:break-word` to fix that

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with javascript. By default a DIV tag will expand to 100% of its parent element.

If you set the width of the div to a specific percentage or pixel width, then the contents of that div will wrap accordingly.

You can use CSS to define the width, but you'll have to know how wide you would like to set it.

```
#mydiv {
    width:50%; //I just guessed at this number
}
```

or

```
#mydiv {
    width:100px; 
}
```

alternately, you could use javascript to set it. (though it's probably best to set it using CSS)

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style = "width:50%';
```

Comment: @squeezebox... i have tried all of above methods but no use. The methods you told me, this is how i am trying to make it work but not working.

Comment: Based on your latest comment about the long words with no whitespace: By default, the browser won't break a word in order to make it wrap. Instead it will wrap at the next white space or word. a very long string of characters with no whitespace will be interpreted as a single word. The chances of such a thing happening in the real world are very very low. If you still need to make that wrap, you can use word-wrap:break-word. thanks @Gabe